# How many levels of nested arrays are possible with parse_ini_file?

Tags: php

How many levels of nested arrays are possible with parse_ini_file?

For instance, can the following array be created?  If so, how?

```
Array
(
    [first_section] => Array
        (
            [one] => 1
            [five] => 5
            [animal] => Dodo bird
        )

    [second_section] => Array
        (
            [second_1] => Array
                (
                    [second_1_1] => 1
                    [second_1_2] => 2
                    [second_1_3] => Array
                        (
                            [second_1_3_1] => one
                            [second_1_3_2] => two
                        )

                )

            [second_2] => two
        )

)
```

Comment: You can sort of express that structure in an INI file, but it would be more easily done with JSON.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I see how I can use process_sections for the first level, and unassociated arrays for the second, but didn't know if I could use associated arrays for the second and third.

Comment: I actually just tested it like `second_1[second_1_1] = 1` and it _does_ work to produce an associative array. It's awkward though because you can't show the nesting well.

Comment: The third level did not work `second_1[second_1_3][second_1_3_1] = one` was an error in the ini file I tested.

Comment: I am testing as well, your just quicker than me :)  Maybe I will add a new answer to the post you referenced?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.